# FME: how to do a multicriteria search on a supplier from a requestior

Tags: python, fme-form, fme-transformer

I have two flows to merge. One is the Contacts table (with fields like "City", "PostalCode", "Address", "CellPhone", "OfficePhone", "Email" etc, and other is the Affairs table, containing also these columns, as brute data. I need to establish a link between an Affair and a Contact, by mathcning data present in "Affairs" table and "Contacts", and adding a
"ContactId" to the "Affair"

I need to associate a Contact to an Affair, but not all the time all informations from Contacts is present in Affair columns, so I need to search like this, first search all common columns between "Affair" and "Contact"

```
"City", "PostalCode", "Address", "CellPhone", "OfficePhone", "Email"
```

if a match is found, OK, add ContactId to respective Affair row, if not, search in order:

```
"PostalCode", "Address", "CellPhone", "OfficePhone", "Email"
"Address", "CellPhone", "OfficePhone", "Email"
"CellPhone", "OfficePhone", "Email"
"CellPhone", "Email"
"Email"
"CellPhone"
```

if any corresponding match, then let "ContactId" empty

To note if the Contact matchs only, say, by City, is not a real match.

What is the best way to do it? I tried FeatureMerger, but that does not allow multiciteria
and match all fields mathced only one from 1500 enties...

[image]

I would prefer one `PythonCaller` to add to the requestor the `ContactId`, insteed of adding multiple FeatureMergers, but don't know how to pass the requestor and supplier to the PythonCaller.
Or maybe there is possible to use `InlineQuerier`?

PS... With 14 criteria, the multiple FeatureMerger is a mess...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in a place I can test this today, but unless you're using a very old FME, there is a "reject" null keys parameter in the FeatureMerger. I think that would reject features without all of the attributes. You could then merge them into a second FeatureMerger, that checks a smaller range of attributes.

That's probably not great practice, but I think it would work, especially since you have a well defined search order.

Other than that, yes the InlineQuerier is a good transformer to use, if you know enough SQL.

Comment: I updated my OP, adding the picture of a multicriteria search using FeatureMerger... is crazy